# Difference between xs:string and xs:string+ in XQuery

Tags: marklogic

What is the difference between `xs:string` and `xs:string+` in XQuery in Marklogic or please point me to an article that can help understand.

Comment: It would also help you if you tagged the questions fully.  Your question(like many recently) are actually about the xQuery programming language and not specific to MarkLogic

Comment: "Tagged the question fully" didn't get you.

Comment: What i meant was: tag the question as xQuery as well as MarkLogic. Your question is specific to the programming language and not the application ..

Answer (score 5):

The difference is:

- `xs:string` represents one string
- `xs:string+` represents a sequence containing one or more strings

You can read more about it [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xquery/0596006349/ch11s06.html).

> An occurrence indicator can be used at the end of a sequence type to indicate how many items can be in a sequence. The occurrence indicators are:
>
> - `?` For zero or one items
> - `*` For zero, one, or many items
> - `+` For one or many items
>   If no occurrence indicator is specified, it is assumed that the sequence can have one and only one item. For example, a sequence type of `xs:integer` matches one and only one atomic value of type `xs:integer`. A sequence type of `xs:string*` matches a sequence that is either the empty sequence or contains one or more atomic values of type ...